# How to solve: premature close at onclosenexttick in Node.js Server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

How to solve this error, I am running my Node.js with AWS IoT then it at times shows this error:

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: How  (/home/ec2-user/work/nodejs_27_01/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:54:                                                                                                     86)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on DeviceClient instance at:
    at MqttClient.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/work/nodejs_27_01/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/                                                                                                     device/index.js:772:15)
    at MqttClient.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at MqttClient.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at TLSSocket.f (/home/ec2-user/work/nodejs_27_01/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at onclosenexttick (/home/ec2-user/work/nodejs_27_01/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:54:                                                                                                     73)
```

Comment: Can you paste out code snippet? It would  help us to guide you.

Comment: Library has  error listner `device.on('error', callback)`, you can consider using it.

Comment: @SandeepPatel from my error listener device.on('error', callback) it bring this Error: **premature close
    at onclosenexttick **

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this:

#### Multiple Connections with same ClientId

The clientId can only be used for one connection at a time. If you connect with the same clientId while another connection is established, the older connection gets dropped (which leads to the premature close error) and the new connection is established.

> The client is using a client ID that is already in use. In this case, the client that is already connected will be disconnected [...]. ([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html))

#### Permissions

This error can happen if a device (mqtt.Client from [aws-iot-device-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#device)) does not hold the correct permissions to connect and/or publish/subscribe/receive messages on a given topic.

See here for more documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html

The policy should look like this (example shows a [Cloudformation Iot Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iot-policy.html) resource):

```
MyIotThingsPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IoT::Policy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Action: iot:Connect
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:client/",
                                 "${iot:ClientId}"] ]
        - Action: iot:Receive
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topic/",
                                "${iot:ClientId}/eg/your/broadcast/topic"] ]
        - Action: iot:Subscribe
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topicfilter/",
                                 "${iot:ClientId}/eg/your/broadcast/topic"] ]
        - Action: iot:Publish
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: !Join [ "", [!Sub "arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topic/",
                                 "${iot:ClientId}/eg/your/publish/topic"] ]
```

The `!Join` is necessary since Cloudformation would try to resolve `${iot:ClientId}`, which is a runtime value, and not known during deployment.

#### Troubleshooting

- As [Sandeep Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4438061/sandeep-patel) also suggests, you should implement an error callback if you want to act on this situation on client side:

  ```
  device.on('error', (error) => {
    // error.message might be 'premature close'
  });
  ```
- You can also look for `disconnectReason` on the topic `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/<clientId>`, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Comment: Thanks at Simons, I will see what I can workaround for this because I had certificates for a single thing which I have built it to be able to read eve other things shadows and updates, now I have to find a way to have an object which will do the work. Subscribing to topics, listening to topics

Comment: Hey guys thank you so much for the assistance. It turned out to be an issue with my clientId. I was using single clientId for multiple devices, my device locally, my co-worker, the EC2 instance. SO the conflict was there. To solve it out I had to add multiple clientId in my Iot policy. Now I no longer have such problem.

Answer (score 1):

While testing, I had attached policy with full `"Action": "iot:*"` permissions, but missed **to activate** the newly created certificate. Please go to IoT core service, `Secure` `-->` `Certificates` and verify the certificate attached to `<Thing>` is activated if you get `error Error: premature close` after you have confirmed the connection to end point with :

`telnet <your-iot-endpoint> 8883`.

See the attached image for the options available with each certificate on above specified page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue using the policy without any restriction and it worked for me.Since I didn't want to restrict to the client connected and the topics subscribed or publihsed I used this policy

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Great thanks this would work too, but I suppose it would just posses you to security risks allowing all client to connect not one defined by you